# Correct way to get UITableViewCell's text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Simple question though, but what is the correct way to get the text off my UITableViewCell?

*With `cell` a [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):*
I know off [`cell.text`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text), which gives exactly what I want, but is deprecated in iOS 3.0.

The only alternative I could find was [`cell.textLabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel) but this gives me the same (or almost?) as if I only used `cell`. Which is obviously not what I want.

So how can I get the text on my cell (what the user reads)? Or is it okay if I leave it as `cell.text` / will Apple accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";` and `NSString *mytext = cell.textLabel.text` as long as you are targeting 3.0 or above.

Comment: Cool. I thought of that after posting the question. Thanks (Will accept when it allows me)